# plot lines to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, immutable.js

I have a working leaflet map where the location is shown real time. The lat and long value comes per second and the map is shown based on that values which changes everytime. Now i want to show the last 10 location history in a polyline but to show the last 10 location as a polyline i need to have an array of 10 locations. How could i create an array with last 10 locations history?

Here is what i have done

```
import L from 'leaflet';

componentDidMount() {
  const { currentValue } = this.props;
  const latestValue = currentValue.split(':');
  const lat = getNumber(latestValue[0]);
  const long = getNumber(latestValue[1]);
  this.map = L.map(this.element).setView([lat, long], 15);

  // Google Map
  L.tileLayer('*****', {
    maxZoom: 20,
  }).addTo(this.map);

  this.marker = L.marker([lat, long], { icon: MarkerIcon });
  this.marker.addTo(this.map);
  const polyLinePoints = [
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
  ];
  const polyLineOptions = {
    color: 'blue',
    weight: '5',
    opacity: 0.9
  };
  const polyline = L.polyline(polyLinePoints, polyLineOptions).addTo(this.map);
  this.map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  const { currentValue } = this.props;
  const latestValue = currentValue.split(':');
  const lat = getNumber(latestValue[0]);
  const long = getNumber(latestValue[1]);
  console.log('lat', lat, long);
  // latlng.push([lat,long]);
  const polyLinePoints = [
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
    new L.LatLng(lat, long),
  ];
  const polyLineOptions = {
    color: 'blue',
    weight: '5',
    opacity: 0.9
  };
  this.marker.remove();
  this.marker = L.marker([lat, long], { icon: MarkerIcon });
  this.marker.addTo(this.map);
  // invalidateSize forces map to recalculate its size
  // next, move the center to given coordinate
  this.map.invalidateSize(false).setView([lat, long]);
  const polyline = L.polyline(polyLinePoints, polyLineOptions).addTo(this.map);
  this.map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
}

render() {
  const { width, height } = this.props;
  return (
    <div
      ref={(element) => { this.element = element; }}
      style={{ width, height }}
    ></div>
  );
}
}
```

I am using leaflet not react-leaflet and immutablejs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each time the location is updated:

- Store a list of 10 latest spots
- Remove the previous polyline (just like what you did with the marker - remove the previous one, or else we're gonna have a memory leak)
- Create new polyline based on the latest list of spots.

You should also create some constants, too (which will be `MAX_SPOT = 10` and `polyLineOptions` - move this outside of componentDidMount() so that we can re-use it every time a new polyline is plotted):

```
// These can be outside of your react class declaration
const MAX_SPOT = 10;
const polyLineOptions = {
  color: 'blue',
  weight: '5',
  opacity: 0.9
};
```

Create some variables for storing `polyLinePoints` and `polyline` (in constructor):

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  // ...
  this.polyLinePoints = [];
  this.polyline = false;
}
```

Next:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // ... keep your previous logics here
  this.polyLinePoints.push(new L.LatLng(lat, long);

  // NOTE HERE: just after the component is mounted, 
  // perhaps there's only 1 location captured, so the polyline should not be created yet
  //this.polyline = L.polyline(this.polyLinePoints, polyLineOptions)
  //this.polyline.addTo(this.map);
  //this.map.fitBounds(this.polyline.getBounds());
}

componentDidUpdate() {  
  // ...your previous logics here
  if (this.polyLinePoints.length < MAX_SPOT) {
    this.polyLinePoints.push(new L.LatLng(lat, long));
  }
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < MAX_SPOT - 1; i++) { // basic for loop ^^
      this.polyLinePoints[i] = this.polyLinePoints[i + 1];
    }
    this.polyLinePoints[MAX_SPOT] = new L.LatLng(lat, long); 
    // so the polyLinePoints should always have 10 latest spots
  }
  this.marker.remove();
  this.marker = L.marker([lat, long], { icon: MarkerIcon });
  this.marker.addTo(this.map);
  // invalidateSize forces map to recalculate its size
  // next, move the center to given coordinate

  // SET THE POLYLINE HERE, remember to remove the previous one, just like your above marker
  // Try..Catch here because the first polyline after componentDidMount() was not created, so your map cannot find the polyline ^^
  try {
    this.map.removeLayer(this.polyline);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }     
  this.polyline = L.polyline(this.polyLinePoints, polyLineOptions)
  this.polyline.addTo(this.map); // the polyline should be added to the map here, should not on the same line as its creation
  this.map.fitBounds(this.polyline.getBounds());
}
```

That is the idea and algorithm, if this doesn't work yet, please show here some errors on the console, thanks!

Comment: I am using immutablejs so this this.polyLinePoints = List([]) would be good i think. i will try this and say if this works or not.

Comment: if this.polyLinePoints = List([]) is used, then the syntax you add new point to it and switch each point to its "next point to the right" may look a bit different, but the algorithm on how to keep only the 10 latest ones should be the same, I think

Comment: Sorry i did not understand switch each point to its "next point to the right". Is not immutablejs List supports push?

Comment: I mean this part:   if there's already 10 points in the list => else {
    for (let i = 0; i < MAX_SPOT - 1; i++) { // basic for loop ^^
      this.polyLinePoints[i] = this.polyLinePoints[i + 1];
    }
    this.polyLinePoints[MAX_SPOT] = new L.LatLng(lat, long); 
    // so the polyLinePoints should always have 10 latest spots
  } => This will make sure that the 11th point should never be added, their position will be moved to the left only (new point will be point 10, point 10 will be point 9... and point 2 will be point 1) ^^

Comment: i got this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_leaflet_id' of undefined
    at Object.stamp (leaflet-src.js:90)
    at NewClass.removeLayer

Comment: I see.. Please see my edited version above. Maybe it was because the first polyline after componentDidMount() was not created, so the map cannot find the polyline object ^^

Comment: i used the condition instead and it worked. But try catch is the effective one.

Comment: Of course we can do it your way, whatever will work! Feel free to post here further issues with this. However, if you've had it working, I'm very glad and expecting an accept as well as an up-vote, thanks ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144045/discussion-between-pythonbeginner-and-thinhvo0108).